# Assert for Json Output in c# Specflow

Tags: c#, api, specflow

I am writing test in specflow to validate an API get output

The code for validation is

```
 [Then(@"the customer details will be returned")]
    public void ThenTheCustomerDetailsWillBeReturned ()
    {
        var actualResponse = ScenarioContextWrapper.Response;
        JObject jsonResult = new JObject();
        jsonResult = JObject.Parse(actualResponse);
        Assert.AreEqual("ABC008", jsonResult.GetType().GetProperty("CustomerCode").GetValue(jsonResult, null));
        Assert.AreEqual("ABC Industry", jsonResult.GetType().GetProperty("CustomerName").GetValue(jsonResult, null));

    }
```

But i am getting exception as "{"Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference"}".

the output for API is

```
              {{
  "Pagination": {
"NumberOfItems": 1,
"PageSize": 200,
"PageNumber": 1,
"NumberOfPages": 1
},
"Items": [
{
  "Addresses": [],
  "CustomerCode": "ABC008",
  "CustomerName": "ABC Industry",
  "GSTVATNumber": null,
  "BankName": null,
  "BankBranch": null,
  "BankAccount": null,
  "Website": null,
  "PhoneNumber": null,
  "FaxNumber": null,
  "MobileNumber": null,
  "DDINumber": null,
  "TollFreeNumber": null,
  "Email": null,
  "EmailCC": null,
  "Currency": {
    "CurrencyCode": "NZD",
    "Description": "New Zealand, Dollars",
    "Guid": "29252c92-3d0e-4eba-a613-f9c6c22ed3a8",
    "LastModifiedOn": "2017-01-31T20:22:20.816Z"
  },
  "Notes": null,
  "Taxable": true,
  "XeroContactId": null,
  "SalesPerson": null,
  "DiscountRate": null,
  "PrintPackingSlipInsteadOfInvoice": null,
  "PrintInvoice": null,
  "StopCredit": false,
  "Obsolete": false,
  "XeroSalesAccount": null,
  "XeroCostOfGoodsAccount": null,
  "SellPriceTier": "",
  "SellPriceTierReference": null,
  "CustomerType": "",
  "PaymentTerm": "",
  "ContactFirstName": null,
  "ContactLastName": null,
  "SourceId": null,
  "CreatedBy": "qa+applicant@tyt.com",
  "CreatedOn": "2017-02-05T18:50:53.697Z",
  "Guid": "15145a60-8688-48a5-b849-ab66da3c0288",
  "LastModifiedOn": "2017-02-05T18:50:53.697Z"
}
]
}}
```

Can someone please help in assert for the customercode

Thanks

Comment: check the properties name. Maybe it will help you understand:  jsonResult.GetType().GetProperties().ToList().ForEach(x=> Console.WriteLine(x.Name));

Comment: @KernelMode Yes , it does not have the property name , Not sure why,  how can i assert the json output?

Comment: I added example in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a short JSON as example because the original in your question is not full:

```
        string actualResponse = "{\"Items\":[{\"CustomerCode\": \"ABC008\", \"TestBla\":\"Bla\"}]}";
        JObject jsonResult = JObject.Parse(actualResponse);

        // Get Null exception. Property does not exist.
        //Object value = jsonResult.GetType().GetProperty("Items").GetValue(jsonResult, null); 

        // Will work
        var items = jsonResult["Items"];

        // To assert CustomerCode:
        string value = jsonResult["Items"][0]["CustomerCode"].Value<string>();
        Assert.AreEqual("ABC008", value);
```

`GetProperty` gets the class property. In your case the class is **JObject**.

if you convert the object to your own class (let's say `Result`) then you can use it own properties (let's say `Item`):

```
    Result result = jsonResult.ToObject<Result>();
    var items = result.Items
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I am very new to this coding world and still trying to work around it, Can you please explain it in little detail as how it will help in asserting the value.